# Distinguish between original and photo-shop

Tags: photoshop

I have a color photo. Is it possible to find out whether it is original or made by
photo-shop?

Comment: Similar: [How can I tell if a photo is real or faked?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/29612/17441) and
[How to identify if a photo is photoshopped without looking at its digital code?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/41834/17441)
Somewhat related: [How was this image where a person appears to lift a paved road created?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/38697/17441)
The question [What must I buy to take amazing product photos?](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/39130/17441) raised some suspicion on the reality of the sample images.

Answer (score 1):

[This page](http://fotoforensics.com/tutorial-ela.php) explains Error Level Analysis (ELA), which can be used on JPEG images to tell from error levels whether an image has been digitally modified. It's not a precise art, though.